# Hyphenation for different document languages (e.g. russian and swedish)

Tags: babel

I am little bit unclear about the impact and the proper definition of the language for a document. e.g.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,russian]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}
\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback("fntFallback",{
    "DejaVu Sans:mode=harf",
    "NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf"})}
\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}
[RawFeature={fallback=fntFallback}
,SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}% fonts for small caps
]
\usepackage{hyphenat} 
\usepackage[pdfa, unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks={true},
    urlcolor={blue},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\small
\item AA - Auswärtiges Amt [Німеччина] (04.01.2022): Алжир: Reise\hyp{} und
Sicherheitshinweise (Teilreisewarnung und COVID\hyp{}19\hyp{}bedingte
Reisewarnung),...       
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

produces [image]

I was expecting that I need to wrap the text with `German` language to have German hyphenated text. But when I just use `swedish` instead of `russian` the hyphenation works properly. [image]

I wouldn't have expected that the language for `swedish` would include German hyphenations.

Hmmm... I am confused about how to configure a document and the langugage.

1. Is it sufficient to use an arbitrary (European) language (e.g. `british`) additionally to `russian` in the document language? Or do I need to have specific languages?
2. Is `russian` the only language which is missing the hyphens for `German`? Or are there others around as well
3. Is there a documentation where I can check which languages are supported with which hyphenation? (I would guess there is a reason why the `German` hyphenation works in `swedish`)
4. Is there any need to wrap a text with the language or is it sufficient to specify it in the beginning of the document? (= what benefits are to wrap the individual text than just specify as document language?)

Note: When I omit the language then the hyphens won't work neither. That's just a detail I observed but I don't need clarification on this.

Comment: You are using `babel`, but haven't specified any languages.  See the `babel` documentation for how to do this and what languages are supported.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more explicitly? To my understanding the language should be forward from the `documentclass` to `babel`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that.  I'm just used to having the languages specified as options to `babel`.  But since you're using more than one (non-English) language, I don't know how to include those in the document class options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. Is Russian the main language, and German a secondary language? From your example it seems the opposite. Anyway, and assuming Russian is the main language, what you want is to consider the text in Latin script is German. If so, here is how to do it (with `\babelprovide` and the option `onchar` the Latin script is mapped to German; I use `\babelfont` to set the font script and language, too):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,russian]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper

\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{german}

\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback("fntFallback",{
    "DejaVu Sans:mode=harf",
    "NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf"})}
    
\babelfont{rm}%
  [RawFeature={fallback=fntFallback}
  ,SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes}
  ,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}% fonts for small caps
  ]
  {Liberation Sans}
  
\usepackage{hyphenat} 
\usepackage[pdfa, unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks={true},
    urlcolor={blue},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\small
\item AA - Auswärtiges Amt [Німеччина] (04.01.2022): Алжир: Reise\hyp{} und
Sicherheitshinweise (Teilreisewarnung und COVID\hyp{}19\hyp{}bedingte
Reisewarnung),...     
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The MWE is really short, perhaps too short - I have to admit. The main language should be Russian. There might be text included which is not Russian, e.g English or German. The selection of the font is NOT the question here. My curiosity is about hyphenation. Why does hyphenation of German text succeeds with document lang swedish but falls with document lang Russian? Plus I have no clue if the same hyphenation problem exists with other language. Or is hyphenation related with the font?

Comment: Each language follows its own rules, so German words aren’t hyphenated because the rules in force in your original example are those from Russian. With `\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{german}` `babel` switch to `german` when a Latin character is found, and therefore the rules for this language are applied. Switching the font (so that the features for the corresponding script/language are applied) may be relevant or not, depending on the script and the font.